# Inject a plus sign between words in a string

Tags: php

Hi I think this is a simple problem to fix but I'm not sure where to look for the answer.

I am attempting to submit a search term to youtube via a simple html form. Everything works fine as long as the search term is limited to a single word such as soda or music. However, when the user inputs a search term with more than one word, such as cold soda or classical music, no results are returned. I noticed that on youtube itself a plus sign gets automatically inserted between words in a search string... so I tried this out by making my search term a constant

```
 $search_term = "cold+soda";
```

and everything worked fine. So my question is given this code:

```
 if(isset($_POST["search_term"])) {
 $search_term = $_POST['search_term'];
 }else {$search_term = $_GET['search_term'];}
```

How would I take the next step and automatically insert a plus sign (+) between multiple search words a user might enter? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/function.urlencode.php) or even better (IMO) [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/function.http-build-query.php)

Comment: Show how you're submitting the query? If you're creating a URL query string, you should be using `urlencode()`, and it will take care of this automatically.

Comment: Thanks so much...that was a really simple fix!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use urlencode function of php

```
urlencode($_GET['search_term'])
```